# jZebra can't print from external server

Tags: java, printing, cross-browser, receipt

I have this problem when using jZebra applet to print receipt.
In local server it has no problems,
but when it is on external server, the applet won't run at all.

Has somebody encountered the same situation here?

Is it a java permission issue, not allowing applet to run on local system,
or it is from the library parameters?

Is there any workaround to make it run on local from server script?
or maybe using cross-browser hack ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

after several research, i have found the cause ...
it's the internal firewall that block java application running from outsider server.

but the failure is from the firewall which doesn't give feedback to block that thing.
so when you stop all the firewall and or any anti-virus in your client machine, it should work.

thanks for my research ;)